# Does razor create multiple instances of an object with a looped partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This question looks mostly to be able to understand the behaviour of razor in this case:

Let's say I have this view called HelloWorld.cshtml:

```
    @model List<String>        

    <div>Hello world</div>
    <h2>Greetings from the whole world!</h2>

    @foreach(String i in Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("GetGreeting", i)
    }
```

And in the partial view GetGreeting.cshtml I have the following:

```
   @model String

   @{ GreetingGetter Greet = new GreetingGetter(); }

   <div>@Greet.foo(Model)</div>
```

How will resource allocation work in a case like this one? I believe that this would allocate a new GreetingGetter with every iteration, but I don't particularly want that, more particularly because the object in a real life scenario might be heavy weight enough to reduce performance with so many senseless allocations.

How does razor treat this under the hood? Will it invoke the code inside the "@{ ... }" everytime inside a foreach loop? Is there a way without changing the model of making this operation more efficient?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a new instance would be created each time.

You could make GreetingGetter static, but that could open up other problems depending on what you're doing with it.

Comment: Thanks, in my case I will end up having to use ViewData for this, since I can't make it static, but I wanted to avoid doing so if there was a chance.